# Three js Preventing raycast picking thru GUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, dat.gui

I need to pick objects by clicking on them and a pop-up non modal dialog to display info about the object. It works as it should, however if the user clicks on any GUI item , including the dialog, and there is an object behind, the three js object will be picked, thus changing the info in the popup.

Here are the snippets.

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
```

jQuery dialog generator:

```
function createDialog(title, text, top) {
      return $("<div class='dialog' title='" + title + "'><p id='bodyText'> " + text + "</p></div>")
      .dialog({ position: { my: ("right" + 0 + "top+" + top), at: "right top" },
      close : setDialogNull, });
}
```

onMouseDown function:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(dialog);
    var mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3();
    mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) - 1;
    mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight );
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouseVector, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objectCollection );

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        var selectedObject = intersects[0];
        console.log("Intersected object", intersects[0]);
        selectedObject.object.material = (selectedObject.object.material.wireframe) ? selectedBoxMaterial : unselectedBoxMaterial;

        var text = intersects[0].distance;
        var title = "Shelf info";

        if (dialog == false) {
            createDialog(title, text, offset);
            offset = offset - 50;
            console.log(offset);
            dialog = true;

            console.log(dialog);
        }   

        if (dialog == true) { 
            {jQuery("#bodyText").text(text);
        }
    }   
}
```

Other GUI elements are created with dat.GUI.

When searching about this issue most results are about Unity, and not being an experienced developer I don't really understand how to adapt to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more code to understand your setup and events it's difficult to know what the solution would be. I would give the element that holds your three.js a specific ID, and in onDocumentMouseDown, check if it's the active element. You may need to check for document.activeElement.parentElement.id, or whatever, depending on what your setup is.

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( e ) {
    if(document.activeElement.id != "myThreeJSElementID"){
        //some other element has been clicked so let's return with nothing:
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(dialog);
    var mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3();
    mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) - 1;
    mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight );
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouseVector, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objectCollection );

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        var selectedObject = intersects[0];
        console.log("Intersected object", intersects[0]);
        selectedObject.object.material = (selectedObject.object.material.wireframe) ? selectedBoxMaterial : unselectedBoxMaterial;

        var text = intersects[0].distance;
        var title = "Shelf info";

        if (dialog == false) {
            createDialog(title, text, offset);
            offset = offset - 50;
            console.log(offset);
            dialog = true;

            console.log(dialog);
        }   

        if (dialog == true) { 
            {jQuery("#bodyText").text(text);
        }
    }   
}
```

More ideally you should be setting a specific event for your three.js container rather than using a global document event, but an exception should work for now. many code examples use document.addEventListener out of simplicity, not best practice.